# Can I move-assign a std::map's contents into another std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Is it possible to insert the contents of a temporary std::map `temp` into another std::map `m` by using move semantics, such that the values from the temporary are not copied and are reused?

Let's say one has:

```
std::map<int, Data> temp;
std::map<int, Data> m;
```

One way of copying values from `temp` into `m` is:

```
m.insert(temp.begin(),temp.end());
```

How can I *move* the `temp` elements into `m`, instead of copying?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**HINT:** *Read the update first!*

The current C++11 standard and the C++14 draft do not provide a member function to enable this feature. As lavr suggested you can still write

```
m.insert(make_move_iterator(begin(temp)),
         make_move_iterator(end  (temp)));
```

which will move the *values* from the source container into the destination container. However, neither the container nodes nor the keys will be moved. This requires memory allocations (at least for the creation of the new nodes in the destination map). The number of elements in the source container will remain the same. The reason behind the copying is simple: The value type of `std::map` is `std::pair<const Key,T>`. And moving from a `const Key` is essentially copying the key (unless someone overloaded the `Key` constructor which takes a `const Key &&`, for which I cannot think of an adequate reason).

If you need to move data from one container to another you may consider using `std::list` instead of `std::map`. It has a [member function `splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) which moves the elements from one list to another in constant time.

**UPDATE:**

Since C++17 there is the function [`std::map::merge()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) which basically puts all the elements of one `std::map` into another `std::map` without moving or copying the actual elements, but by repointing internal pointers only. It is very similar to `std::list::splice()` which exists since C++98.

So you may write

```
m.merge( temp );
```

to accomplish your goal. This is more efficient than copying or moving all the elements from one container to the other.

But beware! Conflicting keys won't be resolved: For coinciding keys nothing will be done.

Comment: While `const Key` will be copied when moving the pair, and while `temp` will keep the same number of elements, `T` will still be moved... so if `T` is a large structure with move semantics like `std::vector`, this still makes sense, right?

Answer (score 12):

Haven't tried, but I think [std::move_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) should help here:

```
 using it = std::map<int, Data>::iterator;
 using mv = std::move_iterator <it>;

 m.insert(mv(temp.begin()),mv(temp.end()));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work for reasons stated above: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:959:14: error: 
      cannot cast from lvalue of type 'const value_type' (aka 'const
      std::__1::basic_string<char>') to rvalue reference type 'reference' (aka
      'std::__1::basic_string<char> &&'); types are not compatible
      return static_cast<reference>(*__i);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible. With other containers, I would suggest the `std::move_iterator` adapter, but that doesn't work because the key of a map is const.

In other words, you can't move elements out one by one from a map because that might change the keys, which a map doesn't allow.

And there is no way to just bulk-move from one map to another. Lists support splicing, but I'm afraid the trees don't.

Comment: I dont quite understand, the underlying types is ``std::pair<const key_type, value_type>``, why might the keys change?, I just extract the ``mapped_type`` from ``temp`` and move it to ``m`` ?

Comment: If you want to move from the element of a map, that's a move operation from that pair. But you can't move from something that is const.